# LibGDX - Moving Body & BodyDef via coordinates sent from server

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-development

I was wondering if there's a way to specifically move the entity / object +5 on the X axis, or specifically say X = 300, Y = 127 for example.

The reason I ask is because I want my game server to be able to specifically set / update player coordinates through a network packet but I can't find any methods that would allow for me to specifically update the coordinates once it has been created and added to the world.

My player / entity structure:

So at the moment, I essentially have a class that extends off an Abstract Class with basic properties in, which looks like the following.

```
public class VisibleEntity extends Entity {

    public String renderImage;
    public Body entityBody;
    public BodyDef bodyDef;


    public VisibleEntity(float height, float width, float positionX, float positionY, boolean isStatic, World world ) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
        this.isStatic = isStatic;
        this.world = world;
        this.entityBody = this.createNewVisibleEntity();
    }

    private Body createNewVisibleEntity() {
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox((this.width / 2) / Store.PIXELS_PER_METER, (this.height / 2) / Store.PIXELS_PER_METER);

        bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = this.isStatic ? BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody : BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(this.positionX / Store.PIXELS_PER_METER, this.positionY / Store.PIXELS_PER_METER);
        bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;

        entityBody = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        entityBody.createFixture(shape, 1f);

        shape.dispose();
        return entityBody;
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {}

    @Override
    public void render() {}

}
```

and I have a player class that has the following method:

```
private void handleInputUpdate() {
    float horizontalForce = 0f;
    float verticalForce = 0f;

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) horizontalForce += 1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) horizontalForce -= 1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) verticalForce += 1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) verticalForce -= 1;

    this.entityBody.setLinearVelocity((horizontalForce * 5), verticalForce * 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of game you're trying to make, if you want it to have snappy movement then this is how you set a body's position:

```
this.entireBody.setPosition(x, y);
```

The more realistic and smoother way to do this is to apply forces to the body as such:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) this.entireBody.applyForce(new Vector2(5f, 0));
```

Comment: That's all fine and good but I'm wanting to be doing server-side valdiation, and so if a player moves to somewhere they shouldn't. I need to be able to manually set their location / co-ordinates via a network packet sent from the server.

Comment: If this is server side code then you will have to do it with set position. If it isn't, you can still use set position on the server, and not on the client.

Comment: Aye but that's what my question is, how do I go about setting the position co-ordinates as I don't seem to see a method for doing so.

Edit: Updated question to be more specific